# Forwarding all mail to a single dev box on IIS via virtual SMTP

Tags: iis, iis-6, smtp

I am trying to set up a development environment for our web server. I would like all emails that are relayed by the server go to a specific mailbox, regardless of who they were sent to. For example, some application on the server sends an email to shopper@yahoo.com. I want that email to go to devbox@mysite.com. Is that possible to do with IIS/Virtual SMTP? Is there some other way of doing this? I don't have exchange server running, if that makes a difference.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIS' SMTP server isn't particularly bright.  I'd recommend using a more intelligent mail server that you control perform the address munging and/or forwarding to a specific address, and having IIS' SMTP server "smart host" to it.

The "more intelligent" mail server need not be a normal mail MTA application; a simple script that opens a network socket, implements just enough SMTP to catch the mail from IIS and write it out to a log file would work just fine.

Comment: Thanks Greg. Is there an open source / free solution for this?

Comment: Found this: http://www.antix.co.uk/Projects/SMTPServerForDevelopers
There is also this: http://www.donovanbrown.com/post/2008/10/20/Neptune.aspx
This is exactly what I need

Answer (score 1):

I normally setup the SMTP server to use a drop directory and avoid the destination mailbox completely. Then give read access to that folder to everyone who needs it.

This also avoids the problem of no SMTP server as part of IIS 7 (on Vista).

If your app is written in .NET you can configure that directly via the `configuration/system.net/mailSettings/smtp` section of `web.config` or `app.config` -- set the `deliveryMethod` attribute to `SpecifiedPickupDirectory`.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good idea. I like a server option better, just because if something goes wrong with the config files, real customers might get dev emails.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a custom server option you might look at [hMailServer](http://www.hmailserver.com/) as well (free and easy to use)